# Prove that $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k\leq m$. And such that exists Bijective function $g:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{<k}$.

Tags: functions

> $k \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> $\mathbb{N}^{< k} = \{ j\in \mathbb{N} |j<k \}$
>
> Let A be a set,Assume $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that exists Injective function
> $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{<m}$

$\textbf{Prove}$ that $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k\leq m$.
And such that exists Bijective function $g:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{<k}$.

**My attempt:** I tried to define $B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ In this way - $B = \{ n\in \mathbb{N}|\: \: \exists\:  Injective \: function\: \:  h:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{<n} \}$.

I dont know how to continue,Thanks.

Comment: The claim does not hold in general. For example, there is an injection from $\left\{ 0 \right\}$ to $\mathbb{N}^{<m}$ for all $m$, but for any $k$ you don't have a bijection.

Comment: I think for $k=1$ you have, for example.

Comment: Of course, sorry. For some reason I read "$\mathbb{N}$" as "$\mathbb{Z}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be such that there is an injection $f: A \to \mathbb{N}^{< m}$. Then $A$ is a finite set (why?). Take $k = \#A$.

Comment: Can you explain yourself ? 
What do you mean when you write $k = \# A$ ?

Comment: By $\# A$ I mean the (finite) cardinality of $A$.

Comment: Ahh ok, I used to write $|A|$.
But,I still dont understand how this helps you.

Comment: Well if $A$ is finite, you can just label the elements as $a_0, \dots a_n$ and define $f(a_i) =i$.

Comment: Ok,I got the idea.
But, How can i write it by algebric way ?

Comment: Well defining the function you can write as I did in the previous comment. But you still need to show that $A$ is finite set, before you get to that point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39527/discussion-between-noam-and-matias-heikkila).